# Trying to understand web-server performance bottleneck

Tags: php, mysql, linux, server, centos

I have a local server running on CentOS 7 (CWP pro). It's primarily used as a web-server (PHP/FPM + MariaDB)

Hardware specs

- Intel Xeon E5-2689 @ 2.60GHz x 16 Cores
- 12GB of DDR3 RAM
- 100GB of NVME storage
- 1Gb/s ethernet connection

Currently there is 1 website hosted (WooCommerce) and it feels pretty slow when I try to open multiple web pages at once without serer-side cache.
**While the pages load slowly, CPU / RAM / SSD usage do not seem to be high at all.**
(according to CWP, CPU never goes over 20%, RAM never goes over 30%)

I've run a few commands to check resource usage, but I'm still very confused about where the bottleneck is.

Can someone please look at these logs and point me in the right direction? Or tell me if I should run some other command to find the issue.

Thanks

[command: top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9RTt.png)

[command: mpstat -P ALL 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evctI.png)

[command: vmstat 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfQPw.png)

[command: iostat -m 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJxvM.png)

Comment: Enable slow PHP-FPM query log. Make sure you have PHP OPcache enabled, etc. Either way, it's not a programming forum, and you can't find your answer anywhere even ServerFault, because CWP Is a panel and panel-related question are offtopic. Install a proper web server base yourself, using *packages* instead of relying on some goofy bash script that compiles everything.

Comment: To speed up WP or Woo:  [_WP Index Improvements_](https://wordpress.org/plugins/index-wp-mysql-for-speed/)

Comment: What ENGINE are you using in MariaDB?